# Best way to make a resizable background?

Tags: html, css

Before anything, I won't provide any of my code because I don't want to use it anymore, i'd rather start fresh with some new ideas

I have to make a div that has a navbar and a background-image in CSS, resize with every resolution, I tried using VW and VH, but whenever I tried resolutions like 1280x1024 and 1024x768, the image would keep it's ratio but would only fill the page width wise, as if there was some margin or padding on top and bottom...showing that the vw and vh were not working.

So my question is, what is the best way to resize a so that the background will always fill the page, even if some of the image is cutout.

Here's an example of a website I found that works exactly the way I had in mind.

http://bigdropinc.com/

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide some sample code of your current site as a starting point.

Comment: @WillReese no code for this one, i'm looking to start from scratch, with some new ideas, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS use

```
background-size:cover;
```